# Button behaves different Locally and deployed on Streamlit cloud

Tags: button, deployment, openai-api, streamlit

I have a streamlit app deployed on the streamlit community cloud using the OpenAi API. My problem is that when I press the button it sometimes triggers the API call once sometimes twice. My question now is what brings the app to reload? I observe this behaviour with printing statements in the log. In general I can observe weird behaviour on the deployed app compared to locally! Is there a difference how streamlit works locally and on the cloud? I feel like the execution order is different.

This is my code:

```
temp_button_AI = st.button(“Use AI model”)

    if temp_button_AI:
        st.session_state.AI_button = True

    if st.session_state.AI_button:
         run_combined_gpt(uploaded_file, selected_option, MODEL='gpt-4-1106-preview', add_on=300)

def run_combined_gpt(uploaded_file, selected_option, MODEL, add_on=300):
    if not validate_input():
        return

    try:
        with st.spinner('Model running, please wait ... !'):

            path = process_file(uploaded_file)
            description_text, mapped_dict = parallel_gpt_tasks(path, selected_option, MODEL, add_on=add_on)
            print("finished")
            sys.stdout.flush()
            st.session_state.description_text = description_text
            st.session_state.mapped_dict = mapped_dict

            st.success('✅✅✅ Model used! ✅✅✅')
            st.session_state.AI_button = False
    except Exception as e:
        st.write("An error occurred:", e)
```

Whithout the session state I have the issue that the app sometimes doesn’t go in the if statement.

Locally the button like this works, it just goes as planned line to line without being reloaded

The application is rather pricey with GPT. So if the button triggers it multiple times it gets super expensive.

I have moved st.session_state.AI_button = False to the end of the st.spinner.
I have done this because without setting it using the temp button to true I am not entering the if statement.
I feel like something inside my function might cause the app to reload and start from the beginning.